# A sensation from the Egyptian cross

Tags: riddle, wordplay

What two-word phrase might describe *the route for a sensation coming all the way from the Egyptian cross*?

It can also be written as *XY where Y is what allows you to do something that sounds like X*. (To avoid ambiguity: X and Y denote strings of letters which when put together form the phrase you seek.)

Comment: @JLee I suggest concentrating on the first paragraph and using the second only to check that you have the right solution.

Comment: I'm guessing "Egyptian cross" is ankh.

Comment: @EngineerToast Nope.

Comment: "all the way **from** the Egyptian cross"  I just don't understand what that could mean. Doesn't it depend on where you are going **to**? Coming from the Egyptian cross to a nearby city, or across the world? The sensation would probably be quite different, no? @EngineerToast ankh is the first thing I found too.

Comment: @JLee "from" isn't really relevant. You might kick yourself when you find the answer! :-)

Comment: While I don't have an answer (and am not really into this type of puzzles), I can't see why it got 2 negative votes so quickly...

Comment: @BmyGuest I know, right? 3 downvotes so far, none of them explained :-(

Comment: Are you referring to [this Egyptian cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Egyptian_Cross_Mystery)

Comment: @BmyGuest Nope. As I said to CodeNewbie, the "cross" is symbolic. What's symbolised by a cross?

Comment: Some random thoughts that might help someone (or be completely off). Maybe "cross" refering to "Christ," maybe indicating an Egyptian God (Ra?).

Comment: @AggieKidd Your first idea is good, but the second one is getting further away again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The route for a sensation:

> A nerve

Coming all the way from the Egyptian cross:

> Coptic

So maybe it is a:

> Coptic nerve

And the second paragraph would be explained as (credit **f''** for this):

> Your optic nerve is what allows you to see/C, so X = C and Y = optic nerve.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE, and well done - you've got the right answer! Can you see how it fits the second paragraph too?

Comment: Had to sleep on it - I think I was overthinking it before. Reminds me of "we live by faith, not by sight".

Comment: I think the second part refers to the fact that the "optic nerve" allows you to "C" (see).

Comment: I don't understand your explanation of the second paragraph. @f'' is correct in his interpretation. Note that I try to make my puzzles objective, rather than pushing any pro-religion (or for that matter anti-religion) views :-)

Comment: Okay, now I C what you were getting at. Thanks!

Comment: If you edit the explanation of the second paragraph, I can accept this answer...

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is...

> Root canal 
> The Egyptian cross is the Suez Canal. And 'route' is a homophone for 'root'. I can't think of an explanation for the second paragraph though.

Comment: I see I was right to put in the 2nd paragraph, otherwise the riddle would've been "too broad" :-) Hint: "cross" is symbolic.

Comment: @randal'thor: So Suez Canal isn't the right reference?